# VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp using Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 + Proguard to strip logs

Tags: android, firebase, crash, android-proguard, verifyerror

In our project we have been using successfully:

- Firebase (for FCM)
- Crashlytics (for reporting crashes)
- Proguard (optimized version)

All was going fine until last week, when we upgraded to `gradle plugin 3.2.0`.

In this version, if we have the following proguard configuration to remove calls to Log:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

when running the app, we get:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.() failed to verify: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(): [0x37] register v0 has type Uninitialized Reference: java.lang.Object Allocation PC: 53 but expected Reference: java.lang.Object
>        void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.firebase.b) failed to verify: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.firebase.b): [0x3C] register v8 has type Uninitialized Reference: com.google.firebase.internal.a Allocation PC: 58 but expected Reference: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$a
>        com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.a(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.b, java.lang.String) failed to verify: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.a(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.b, java.lang.String): [0x17] register v1 has type Uninitialized Reference: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$1 Allocation PC: 21 but expected Reference: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.a$a (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk)`

If we remove that config to strip the calls to **`Log`** all is fine, as it was in the previous version of the gradle plugin (3.1.4).

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: The same problem here and it happens in different places everytime. This grade plugin version is not stable at all... The problem occurs if I use proguard optimized rules, but not if simple rules. Revert back to version 3.1.4 for now

Comment: @don11995 Check the solution provided by Aybareon, it worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like there is some problem with proguard `-assumenosideeffects` and `Log`.

Try using `-assumenosideffects` only on the methods you use and whichever methods that depend on those `Log` methods.

Something like:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

instead of the usual

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {*;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working for me. I already have the rules that mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. The problem was in the other `assumenosideeffects` rules, particularly in `*** <init>(...);` rule. After removing this line everything is working.