# VerifyError: Verifier rejected class ... 'this' arg must be initialized

Tags: android, gradle, verifyerror

after third-party library upgrade I got a new crash on app launch:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class ly.img.android.e: void ly.img.android.e.<init>(java.lang.String, boolean) failed to verify: void ly.img.android.e.<init>(java.lang.String, boolean): [0x5C] 'this' arg must be initialized (declaration of 'ly.img.android.e' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
    at ly.img.android.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source:46)
    at ly.img.android.c.b(Unknown Source:0)
    at ly.img.android.PESDK.initSDK(Unknown Source:0)
    at ly.img.android.IMGLYAutoInit.onCreate(IMGLYAutoInit.java:41)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
```

Yes, I know that there are a lot of similar problems there but I didn't find any solution or advise for me.

So, maybe someone there can provide hint or advise for me what's wrong there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did I resolve the issue:

I have upgraded ***gradle*** version from `3.5.3` to `3.6.3`. Ough and thank you. Maybe my experience can help somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Others were also facing this kind of issue, I think this can help you! ⛅

`java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class ly.img.android.e: void ly.img.android.e.<init>(java.lang.String, boolean) failed to verify: void ly.img.android.e.<init>(java.lang.String, boolean): [0x5C] 'this' arg must be initialized (declaration of 'ly.img.android.e' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)`

But according to a GitHub thread they found a solution to this problem

https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-android-sdk/issues/15#issuecomment-454842450

> The fix for this issue is available for AGP(Android Gradle Plugin) 3.3 (and 3.4) by setting an explicit dependency detailed below.
>   After AGP 3.3.1 is released, remove the pinned version to allow you to pick up new D8/R8 releases again.

For AGP 3.3 amend your top-level build.gradle file with:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw" // ADD THIS.
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.3.52'  // ADD THIS. Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
    }
}
```

For AGP 3.4 the r8 version should be 1.4.25

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion
Maybe it will help

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
       ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the probelm with third-party library.

In my case, I built the library *.jar* myself and had no idea why the `VerifyError` would appear when trying to test the *.jar* in a test application.

The problem was in `proguard.cfg` with `-assumenosideeffects` and `Log`.

Specifically, inside `proguard.cfg` (of my library) there was a following line:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {*;}
```

Replacing it with:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

and building and obfuscating it again resolved the problem.

I found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608266/7111456).

I know this doesn't directly answer to the original question, but I left this answer here in order to help someone who is trying to build the *.jar* and the result of using it is `VerifyError`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Connection#7864356
    Process: ..., PID: 24458
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class r8.a: r8.b r8.a.b(w8.a[]) failed to verify: r8.b r8.a.b(w8.a[]): [0x33] expected to be within a catch-all for an instruction where a monitor is held (declaration of 'r8.a' appears in /data/app/~~DIy9qxh1lGM...==/base.apk)
        at p7.g$b.b(SourceFile:270)
        at p7.g$b.run(SourceFile:35)
```

This happened after I updated gradle from `4.2.2` to `7.3.1`. I tried disabling obfuscation and the @Keep option for the specified classes in the error message. But nothing helped. In debug mode, everything still worked, but in the release the app crashed with an error.

Thanks Dupinder Singh.
I've changed my top-level build.gradle file with:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:4.0.48'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now everything works. Maybe my solution will help someone.